# How to add a second input argument (the first is an image) to a CNN model built with Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

Let's say I have a list of *images* (converted to numpy arrays) downloaded from Instagram, along with their corresponding *likes* and user *followers*. And let's say I have a **CNN model** (using **Keras** on **Tensorflow**) which I train on these images (200x200x3 numpy arrays) and it tries to predict the number of *likes* an image will get.

What if I want to give to this model each image's corresponding *followers* as a **second input**?

This is my code so far:

```
IMAGESIZE = (200, 200)

def create_model():
    # create model and add layers
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(10, 5, 5, activation='relu',
                     input_shape=(IMAGESIZE[0], IMAGESIZE[1], 3)))

    model.add(Conv2D(10, 5, 5, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPool2D((5, 5)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(50))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    print(model.summary())

    model.compile(loss='mse',
                  optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model

# Read the likes
likes = getlikes(src='../data/pickledump')
likesraw = np.array(likes)
likes = (likesraw - np.mean(likesraw))/np.std(likesraw)  # normalize

# Read the images and resize them
images = []
for imgfile in glob.glob('../data/download/*.jpeg'):
    img = cv2.imread(imgfile)
    resized = cv2.resize(img, IMAGESIZE)
    images.append(resized)
    break
images = np.array(images)

# Read the followers
followers= getfollowers(src='../data/pickledump')
followersraw= np.array(followers)
followers= (followersraw- np.mean(followersraw))/np.std(followersraw)  # normalize

classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=20)
print("Accuracy (Cross Validation=10): ",
      np.mean(cross_val_score(classifier, images, likes, cv=2)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use a two branch model, where one branch processes the image and another branch processes other non-image inputs (such as posts texts or number of followers and followings, etc.). Then you can merge the result of these two branches and possibly add a few other layers afterwards to act a the final classifier/regressor. To build such a model in Keras you need to use the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) instead. Just for demonstration, here is an example:

```
inp_img = Input(shape=image_shape)
inp_others = Input(shape=others_shape)

# branch 1: process input image
x = Conv2D(...)(inp_img)
x = Conv2D(...)(x)
x = MaxPool2D(...)(x)
out_b1 = Flatten()(x)

# branch 2: process other input
out_b2 = Dense(...)(inp_other)


# merge the results by concatenation
merged = concatenate([out_b1, out_b2])

# pass merged tensor to some other layers
x = Dense(...)(merged)
output = Dense(...)(x)

# build the model and compile it
model = Model([inp_img, inp_other], output)
model.compile(...)

# fit on training data
model.fit([img_array, other_array], label_array, ...)
```

Note that we used `concatenation` layer above, but there are other [merge layers](https://keras.io/layers/merge/) which you can use. And make sure you read the [functional API guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/), it's a must-read guide.